# CS50's Readability/ How can i use my functions?

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int count_letters(string);
int count_words(string);
int count_sentences(string);

float l, w, s;

int main(void)
{
    //Get text
    string text = get_string("Text:");

    //Get the length of text
    int i = strlen(text);

    //Coleman-Liau index
    float L = 100.0f * (l / (float)w);
    float S = 100.0f * (s / (float)w);
    int index = round(0.0588 * L - 0.296 * S - 15.8);

    if (index < 1)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (index > 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %i\n", index);
    }

}

int count_letters(string text)
{
    //Letters start from 0
    l = 0;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))
        {
            l++;
        }
    }
    return l;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    //Spaces + 1 equals to count of words
    w = 1;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        //Space equals to number 32 in ASCII Chart
        if(text[i] == ' ')
        {
            w++;
        }
    }
    return w;
}

int count_sentences(string text)
{
    s = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(text); i < n; i++)
    {
        if(text[i] == '!' || text[i] == '.' || text[i] == '?')
        {
            s++;
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

The index is always the same negative number so I can only get "Before Grade 1" output because i don't use any of my created functions.

I have created 3 functions below my code but I don't know how to use them in main.I want my functions to be able to calculate the count of letters(l), words(w) and sentences(s) in a text in order to find the index.Can you help me?

Comment: What value do you expect `L` and `S` to have?

Comment: *I don't know how to use them in main* What exactly is unclear about calling your own function? Of course you must call them before you calculate your index. Just call each of the functions and assign the return value to a variable. There is no need to mess around with global variables. You should remove them.

Comment: `l / (float)w` is first executed as `0 / (float)0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a variable and then call the function. The value returned by that function (hopefully an integer in this case) would be stored in it. Just as an example,

```
int l = count_letters(text);
```

Do the same thing for the other 2 functions and you are done.
Also define this before Coleman-Liau index expressions.

> Also remove those global variables (on line 11 probably) you don't need those.